# Update manually commit and branch attributes from jenkins pipeline blueocean

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We are using jenkins for manual triggered jobs to deploy some code.
Jenkinsfile describing our pipeline is located in a jenkinsfile dedicated repo (not in deployed code repo).

We are using declarative pipeline syntax and shared libraries in our jenkinsfiles.

In BlueOcean interface there are 2 interesting attributes (branch and commit) automatically filled when using plugins to trigger pipelines (like github organization).
I'm searching a way to set/update these 2 attributes manually from within the pipeline code for our manual pipelines.

Job description and name can be easily updated using something like :

```
stage('Set pipeline description'){
    steps {
        script {
            currentBuild.description = "Deploying branch ${branch} on ${targetEnv}"
        }
    }
}
```

But I didn't find anywhere how to update branch or commit values.

Did anybody try this ?

Comment: When you have your `Jenkinsfile` in a repo, this automatically determines the branch and commit, right?

Comment: In my case no, it seems to be because of job is launched manually (not by github organization plugin trigger). commit and branch are empty.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is reported as bug (see [link](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-54365)).

> *"We are using GitLab web hooks to trigger Jenkins Pipeline project builds on new commit push to GitLab. Build is triggered, CI commit status report is being sent back to gitlab, but can't see branch and commit field in Header-details element."*

Please vote on this issue on Jenkins CI website if you want for the issue to be resolved sooner.

Comment: That's not same use-case as us as we wanted to be able to modify these fields from inside pipeline stages from a manually triggered pipeline.